# How to fix the node.js code to check for login

Tags: mysql, sql, node.js

I am new to node js and dont know why is this returning the false value always. I have form made in html that sends post request then the app.js calls login.js function and checks the database

I tried to manually input with 2 var and it works but when using the form it doesnt.

```
app.post('/login', urlencodedParser, function (req, res) {
  var check = require('./js/login.js');
  var username = req.body.username;
  var password = req.body.password;
     if(check([username,password]) == true){
        console.log('fine');
        res.render('index');
     }
     else{
        console.log('get lost');
        res.render('login');
     }
});
```

This is the app.js code thet calls the login.js but the page doesnt render also even if the returned value is incorrect.

```
var check = function(arr){
  var con = require(__dirname + '/database.js');
  var login_check = false;
  con.connect(function(err) {
    if (err) throw err;
    con.query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE (name = ?) AND (password = ?)", [arr[0], arr[1]], function (err, result, fields) {
      if (err) throw err;
      if(result)
      {
        login_check = true;
      }
    });
  });
  return login_check;
};

module.exports = check;
```

Comment: I short: You are assuming  synchronous  code - but writing  asynchronous  code. login_check will always be false like this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because of your `con.query` function is asynchronous, so the return of function will always be false by default (it returns before executing check). Another way, you can try to use callback function as my suggestion code below:

```js
app.post("/login", urlencodedParser, function(req, res) {
  var check = require("./js/login.js");
  var username = req.body.username;
  var password = req.body.password;
  var checkCallback = function (isLogin) {
      if (isLogin) {
        console.log("fine");
        res.render("index");
      } else {
        console.log("get lost");
        res.render("login");
      }
  }
  check([username, password], checkCallback);
});

// -----------------------------
// login.js
var check = function(arr, callback) {
  var con = require(__dirname + "/database.js");
  var login_check = false;
  con.connect(function(err) {
    if (err) throw err;
    con.query(
      "SELECT * FROM users WHERE (name = ?) AND (password = ?)",
      [arr[0], arr[1]],
      function(err, result, fields) {
        if (err) throw err;
        if (result) {
          login_check = true;
          callback(true); // Call the callback function here after checking is done
        }
      }
    );
  });
  return login_check;
};

module.exports = check;
```